# Having archived applications on MacOS. How to tell OS to ignore them?

Tags: macos, mojave, spotlight

So I have a folder of applications that I don't use but I might need in the future.

However, these applications, even on a secondary or external disk, in any folder, will prompt MacOS to scan and offer all kinds of services for one, and two open them if there are files that could be associated with them.

I just want them to stand aside. I currently have them in a hidden folder and they seem to still popup.

Spotlight index has been set to ignore them several time. Still occurs.

Comment: I haven't tried it but I guess that changing the name from `foo.app` to `foo.disabled` will work.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to zip each one. Right-click and select "Compress Name.app" (where Name is the name of the app).

Then delete the app. If you want to restore it, just double click on the zip file, and the app will get re-created.

Other possibilities include putting them inside a disk image, and then unmounting it.

Any method in which the app is no longer available to the OS will work. Otherwise, if the OS can 'see' the app, then it will be considered as viable and integral.

Comment: I am not going to start zipping stuff. I can also move them to a usb disk and unplug it. Not a great solution. How the hell can there not be a better way? Just having apps lying around and MacOS starts adding their funcitonality without being prompted to do so. Sounds dangerous.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you mean by "prompts MacOs to scan and offer all kinds of services"? What behaviour are you seeing? There may be a way to minimize these. However, generally, any application on any mounted disk is available to the OS for linking to file types. So you'll see it in the "Open With" menu, but that's the extent of its effect.

Comment: yes, that is the annoyance. also, apps from those disks will sometime open there as well. services menu in keyboard settings gets polluted as well. it's annoying as hell. I want things to be clean. i can not find my services if everytime i hook a usb to my disk it will get dirtied.

Comment: The Keyboard System Preference is where you control whether you want Services from applications to show or not.

Comment: @momomo why don't you want to zip the apps? It's easy and effective.

Comment: Because i might wish to use them on occasion. And prefer not having to unzip them, and then having to delete them again.

Comment: You can choose where you want the inconvenience: in the Services and Open With menu; in zipping and unzipping; or in keeping them on an unmounted volume.

Comment: Probably easier to just rename them to .disabled if that works. will try later.